# Expandable List + Other Fragments in a single Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to add multiple fragments in a single layout. However, I'm getting errors when I include additional fragments. Kindly assist.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#F0F8FF"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>

      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragw3"
        android:name="com.example.engineercalclist2.arrayHistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting? can you please enlighten us more.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood right, but here it goes:

Instead of adding `Fragments` directly from xml, you can use a `FrameLayout`. Then on your code ,lets say when you click on your `ExpandableListView` item, you can change the fragment. Here is a simple example.

Add this to your xml.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Now move on  to your Activity, declara a `Fragment`

```
 Fragment fragment = null;
```

Then on your `OnItemClickListener` for your `ExpandableListView` set the `fragment` to the fragment you want to change like this.

```
 fragment = new Fragment_ToGo();
```

Then use this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment); 
ft.commit();
```

**EDIT**

Now, I'm going to use the tutorial from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html). I suggest you to read there first, down below is my explanation.

First of all, if your API is older than 11 your MainActivity ,which contains Fragments,  should be extended to `FragmentActivity`. If you are using API 11 or newer, you are good to go.

Now, create your Fragment(s) like this.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is going to be your Activity's XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And finally, your MainActivity:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);
    }
}
```

Now since i don't know what error do you get, I'm only able to help you to this point. I will edit my answer again when you post your `Logcat`.

Comment: Thank you. But my intention is to have 3 sections in my main layout. 1)Expandable list. 2)Fragment opens up after clicking from expandable list. 3) One more fragment that always remain in the layout that gets updated from the selected fragment. So would I be able to use the above mentioned method?

Comment: Oh, then can you post your errors you got? I'm going to edit my answer according to that.

Comment: The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project ExpandListSample  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: 02-22 12:01:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 12:01:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.engineercalclist2/com.example.engineercalclist2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
02-22 12:01:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-22 12:01:03.144: E/AndroidRuntime(1491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

Comment: That should be about cleaning your project, click on Project from the top menu then clean. If it doesn't work try re-opening eclipse. Besides from that, it could be causing from your XML file, one typo could mess the project.

Comment: if i remove the fragment portion from the xml it works well. So how to include the fragment? Thanks again.

Comment: See my edit above, check the Class path carefully, i mean `android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"`part.

Comment: Thank you. Im able to have multiple layout using a new xml and java file. I believe there is some logical fault in my previous xml and java code. However, Im still unable to update a value in fragment from another fragment. I'll try to resolve it.